# Casting issue with KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, linq, keyvaluepair

I have a list of KeyValuePair which I want to search through. The search function I have written this way:

```
public KeyValuePair<string, OperationInstance> operationInstanceLookupByName(string pOperationInstanceName)
{
    KeyValuePair<string, OperationInstance> lResultOperationInstance = new KeyValuePair<string,OperationInstance>();
    try
    {
        var result = cOperationInstanceNameLookup.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == pOperationInstanceName);
        if (result.Count() != 0)
            lResultOperationInstance = result;
        else
            cOutputHandler.printMessageToConsole("Operation Instance " + pOperationInstanceName + " not found in Dictionary!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
```

What is the problem in this assignment:

```
lResultOperationInstance = result;
```

and how can I solve it?

Comment: What error/exception do you get?

Comment: What type is `cOperationInstanceNameLookup`? Most KeyValuePair collections have a `TryGetValue` function for lookups.

Comment: If you already have the `string` key value why do you need to return a `KeyValuePair` instead of just a `OperationInstance`?

Comment: The error I get on the line I mentioned above is: " Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,ProductPlatformAnalyzer.OperationInstance>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,ProductPlatformAnalyzer.OperationInstance>'"

Comment: I do not want to return KeyValuePair in this function, but I thought I had to as this is what the lookup.where is returning.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Where` you are getting a collection rather than a single result. Use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` or `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` instead:

```
var result = cOperationInstanceNameLookup.SingleOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == pOperationInstanceName);
if (result != null)
    ...

.FirstOrDefault will return the first matching item or null if not found.
.SingleOrDefault will return the matching item if there is only one, or null if there isn't or an exception if there are multiple.
```

A better approach however would be to get the instance using the dictionary as intended.

The following will find the item from the dictionary but will throw an exception if it does not exist:

```
OperationInstance result = cOperationInstanceNameLookup[pOperationInstanceName];
```

You could test it first with .ContainsKey but the following approach will attempt to get the value and allow you to check it's existence at the same time. This is the fastest approach:

```
OperationInstance result = null;
if (cOperationInstanceNameLookup.TryGetValue(pOperationInstanceName, out result))
    // result will be populated
else
    // result is still null
```

Comment: I think their case specifically calls for `FirstOrDefault`, then they can check if the result is `null` instead of checking a `Count`.  `SingleOrDefault` only if they want an exception thrown when there is more than one match.

Comment: FYI `SingleOrDefault` will return the default value (`null` for reference type) if there are no matches, the match if there is exactly one, or throw an exception if there is more than one (that last bit is how it differs from `FirstOrDefault`)

Answer (score 0):

To get the result from your dictionnary you should use

```
cOperationInstanceNameLookup[pOperationInstanceName]
```

and to test if the dictionnary contains your key

```
cOperationInstanceNameLookup.ContainsKey(pOperationInstanceName)
```

You ll get better performance !

So something like this should do the trick (thanks @juharr):

```
    public KeyValuePair<string, OperationInstance> operationInstanceLookupByName(string pOperationInstanceName)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, OperationInstance> lResultOperationInstance =
            new KeyValuePair<string, OperationInstance>();

        OperationInstance value;
        if (cOperationInstanceNameLookup.TryGetValue(pOperationInstanceName, out value))
            lResultOperationInstance = new KeyValuePair<string, OperationInstance>(pOperationInstanceName, value);
        else
            cOutputHandler.printMessageToConsole("Operation Instance " + pOperationInstanceName + " not found in Dictionary!");

        return lResultOperationInstance;
    }
```

Comment: This of course assumes that it's a dictionary and not a list of `KeyValuePair`s.

Comment: I assumed it's a dictionnary because of the error message ^^ `"Operation Instance " + pOperationInstanceName + " not found in Dictionary!"`

Comment: Missed that by not scrolling.  But in that case a `TryGetValue` would be better than potentially doing two look-ups with `ContainsKey` and the indexer.